# stopping a process on dlopen failure

Tags: linux, gcc, dlopen

<sup>Perhaps a border-line question, more related to debugging & sysadmin that stricto sensu to coding</sup>

I'm working (on Debian/Sid/x86-64) on preparing the next [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) release, it is a complex meta-plugin for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) providing (thru a free software GPLv3 plugin) a domain specific language for GCC translated to C++.

<sup>(If you want the current snapshot, download http://gcc-melt.org/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27.tar.bz2 it has 3.8Mbytes)</sup>

The building procedure of MELT is arcane and takes 15 minutes (on i7 3770K). It involves several runtime-generated C++ code and generated shell scripts and complex makefiles. So it is a nightmare.

I have a bug in some of my code. A `dlopen` is failing. The `dlopen` is done by some *system* GCC compiler (actually of course it is the `cc1plus`...). This happens in deeply nested scripts (e.g. a `make` invoking an `autogen` generation of a shell script, then that generated shell script is invoking another `make`, which invokes that GCC command; some shell or make variables are incorrect...).

Of course the system `cc1plus` is rightly giving fatal error on `dlsym` failure.

My bug (somewhere, don't now yet where) is that some shell or environment or `make` variable is wrongly transmitted, and instead of invoking the `/usr/bin/g++-4.8` compiler, some intermediate script is invoking `/usr/bin/g++` on my Debian where the default `g++` is a `g++-4.9`

Of course I don't want to recompile my system `/usr/bin/g++-4.8` or `/usr/bin/g++-4.9`

#### Question:

**Is it possible** (perhaps thru *oprofile* or `LD_PRELOAD`  cute tricks?) **to run a complex set of processes** (some of them being `g++` or `g++-4.8`) **and either stop, or breakpoint, any `cc1plus` or `cc1`** (either in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.3/` or in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1`) **whose `dlopen` is failing?**

<sup>If the faulty process `cc1plus` doing the failing `dlopen` was stopped -without exiting- I could trace all the scripts and `make` chains starting it.</sup>

#### gory details

If you are brave enough to try reproduce my bug (I don't ask that, it is time consuming!) download my [`melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27.tar.bz2`](http://gcc-melt.org/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27.tar.bz2) and on a Debian/Sid having both `gcc-4.8` (4.8.3) and `gcc-4.9` (4.9.1) installed and their plugin-dev (with the default `/usr/bin/gcc` being the 4.9.1 version), extract my plugin snapshot into `/tmp` and type `make MELTGCC=gcc-4.8 GCCMELT_CXX=g++-4.8` in the extracted directory `/tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/`

At the end I'm getting incorrectly

```
 MELT BUILD SCRIPT INFO: meltfrom=melt-build-script.tpl:375/230-melt-build-script.tpl:451/377 meltmode=translateinit meltbase=warmelt-first meltstage=meltbuild-stage1 meltprevstage=meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt meltinit=meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-first.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-base.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-debug.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-macro.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-moremacro.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-normal.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-normatch.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-genobj.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-outobj.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-hooks.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-modes.quicklybuilt meltinclude= meltsrc=/tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/melt/warmelt-first.melt
 MELT BUILD SCRIPT INFO: melt-build-script.tpl:375/230-melt-build-script.tpl:451/377 emit C++ code for warmelt-first of meltbuild-stage1
 MELT BUILD SCRIPT INFO: melt-build-script.tpl:375/230-melt-build-script.tpl:451/377 argument file meltbuild-stage1/warmelt-first.args is
 -Wno-shadow -frandom-seed=ea257ebecb10e5a2143d906632a799b0
  -DGCCMELT_FROM_ARG="melt-build-script.tpl:375/230-melt-build-script.tpl:451/377"
  -fplugin-arg-melt-mode=translateinit
  -fplugin-arg-melt-arg=/tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/melt/warmelt-first.melt
  -fplugin-arg-melt-output=meltbuild-stage1/warmelt-first
  -fplugin-arg-melt-module-make-command='make'
  -fplugin-arg-melt-module-makefile=/tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/melt-module.mk
  -fplugin-arg-melt-module-cflags='-I /tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27 -I /tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/melt/generated  -I. -Imeltbuild-stage1 -Imeltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/plugin/melt-headers/1.1-rc1-snap-svnrev-213094 -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/plugin/include -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/plugin/include/c-family -I /tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27/melt/generated -I /tmp/melt-plugin-snapshot-r213101-2014july27'
  -fplugin-arg-melt-init=meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-first.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-base.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-debug.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-macro.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-moremacro.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-normal.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-normatch.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-genobj.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-outobj.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-hooks.quicklybuilt:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt/warmelt-modes.quicklybuilt
  -fplugin-arg-melt-workdir=meltbuild-workdir
  -fplugin-arg-melt-tempdir=meltbuild-tempdir
  -fplugin-arg-melt-source-path=meltbuild-stage1:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt:.
  -fplugin-arg-melt-module-path=meltbuild-stage1:meltbuild-stage0-quicklybuilt:.
  -fplugin-arg-melt-bootstrapping
  -fplugin-arg-melt-generate-work-link
  -fplugin-arg-melt-generated-c-file-list=meltbuild-stage1/warmelt-first.cfilist
 meltbuild-empty-file.c
 cc1plus: error: cannot load plugin ./melt.so
 ./melt.so: undefined symbol: _Z28gt_ggc_mx_gimple_statement_dPv
 MELT BUILD SCRIPT FAILURE: melt-build-script.tpl:375/230-melt-build-script.tpl:451/377 failed with arguments @meltbuild-stage1/warmelt-first.args
 Makefile:429: recipe for target 'melt-translator' failed
 make: *** [melt-translator] Error 1
 rm gfmeltgcc_revision _melt-runtime.c gfmeltgcc_run_md5 gfmeltgcc_version_number _meltrunsup-inc.c
 make MELTGCC=gcc-4.8 GCCMELT_CXX=g++-4.8  77.48s user 3.79s system 98% cpu 1:22.34 total
```

Of course a `g++-4.9` is *incorrectly* `dlopen`-ing a `melt.so` for GCC 4.8. The bug is mine, something is starting `g++` instead of `g++-4.8` (which should have been transmitted by `make` and shell variables).

---

### workaround ....

I did not found an answer to my question, but I made a workaround: I patched GCC 4.9.1 source code (file `gcc/plugin.c` function `try_init_one_plugin`) to add some statements after failing `dlopen` e.g.

```
  dl_handle = dlopen (plugin->full_name, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  if (!dl_handle)
    {
      char*errmsg = xstrdup(dlerror ());
      fprintf(stderr,
              "\n @@ GCC PLUGIN LOAD FAILURE pid %d %s: %s\n",
              (int) getpid(), plugin->full_name, errmsg);
      fflush(NULL);
      system("pstree -a -h -l -s");
      system("ps auxw");
      fflush(NULL);
      fprintf(stderr, 
              "\n @@ GCC PLUGIN LOAD FAILURE sleeping 8 seconds\n");
      fflush(NULL);
      sleep (8);
      fprintf(stderr, 
              "\n @@ GCC PLUGIN LOAD FAILURE selfstopping\n");
      fflush(NULL);
      sleep (1);
      kill (SIGSTOP, getpid());
      fflush(NULL);

      error ("cannot load plugin %s\n%s", plugin->full_name, errmsg);
      free (errmsg);
      return false;
    }
```

The `fprintf`, `system` and `fflush` (with the `strdup` and `free` of result of `dlerror` ...) calls above form my temporary patch. Then I compiled my patched GCC 4.9.1 and using `PATH` tricks ensured that it was called.

With that, I was able to correct my initial bug.

Patching `dlopen` would be difficult and quite dangerous (too often used in too many places).

I also thought of process accounting [acct(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html) & [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html) ...). Finally patching GCC was the most easy (but a bit shameful) thing to do.

<sup>BTW, such bugs is why I believe more and more in free software. If my compiler accepting plugins was closed-source, I would have much more hard time finding the bug.</sup>

N.B. I will remove the plugin snapshot in a few days.

Comment: Can you modify the code of dlopen() to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `dlopen` implementation (ie the dynamic linker). I'm trying to compile my patched gcc-4.9.1 (which I do know quite well, at least the plugin part). But I wanted to avoid that and I feel ashamed.